# How to rename field inside object

Tags: arrays, react-native, sorting

I found some solutions but not exactly what I wanted. I want to change the field name inside the object name where condition I will explain by the following example for if

```
array=[{

        "mobile1": [{
            "screensize": "6.5"
        }]
    },
    {

        "mobile2": [{
                "screensize": "6.5"
            },
            {
                "price": "2000"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to change mobile1 to newmobile final output will be

```
[{

        "newmobile": [{
            "screensize": "6.5"
        }]
    },
    {

        "mobile2": [{
                "screensize": "6.5"
            },
            {
                "price": "2000"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `input.map(i => { const {x, ...rest} = i; return x ? {...rest, a: x} : rest})` you should be able to change `const input = [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 11, y: 22}, {z: 111, y: 222}]` into `[{y:2,a:1},{y:22,a:11},{z:111,y:222}]`.
Could this work for you?

UPDATE

My solution takes advantage of JavaScript's [destructuring assignment with spread operatr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). You can find below a running snippet:

```js
const input = [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 11, y: 22}, {z: 111, y: 222}]
const output = input.map(i => { const {x, ...rest} = i; return x ? {...rest, a: x} : rest})
console.log(output)
```

So, in your case, you have

```js
const input = [{

        "mobile1": [{
            "screensize": "6.5"
        }]
    },
    {

        "mobile2": [{
                "screensize": "6.5"
            },
            {
                "price": "2000"
            }
        ]
    }
]

const output = input.map(i => { const {mobile1, ...rest} = i; return mobile1 ? {...rest, newmobile: mobile1} : rest})

console.log(output)
```

and the produced output is the one you need.
I hope this can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: can you provide full-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let c = [{

        "mobile1": [{
            "screensize": "6.5"
        }]
    },
    {

        "mobile2": [{
                "screensize": "6.5"
            },
            {
                "price": "2000"
            }
        ]
    }
]
let final = c.map(i=>{
     let x = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(i)
     if(x=="mobile1"){
     console.log(i.mobile1)
       return {"newmobile":i.mobile1}
     }
     else {
         return i
     }
 })
console.log("final output",final);
```

Comment: wow, perfectly works!